# How do I install Arch using an older kernel? No ISOs seem to exist

Tags: arch-linux, virtual-machine, vmware

This is my first time in Arch, and I'm following [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSGWiFOp_7o&list=PLj97-HQdMXyZSvMD1xRTqPEeh4nSA6dpC) tutorial, which is great, except that I can't go any farther than partitioning the drive. The reason is that when I try to mount my newly-made partitions, I hit an error that gives me

> sda1: WRITE SAME failed. Manually zeroing.

Then it just sits there, not giving me back the command line.

I thought maybe it was "manually zeroing" something, so I let it work, but it never came out of it. So I went looking for help online. I found [this forum entry](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=161843) that recommended a different kernel, the LTS release.

I've been back to the Arch website to download the older image, but I can't find it anywhere. I did find an LTS kernel [here](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/linux-lts/) but that can't be what I need, it's only 46 Mb in size. I need the ISO so I can install from scratch - I don't have a running install that I can grab just the kernel with.

I hunted around some more and saw that someone had recommended trying

```
pacman -S linux-lts
```

but that just came back, telling me that the databases could not be found, or reached, or whatever.

Does anyone know how I can install Arch using the LTS kernel?

Comment: Use your `archiso` and on install LTS kernel live to your target via pacman with - pacstrap $TGT_MNT base base-devel linux-lts. When you mkinitcpio make sure you use the -p linux-lts. Also, 46mbs more than enough to be your kernel package - a lot more than enough.

Comment: Use the Beginners Guide for the install instructions; random videos are likely out of date or just plain wrong.